# I am trying to add an additional 'Bye' command in the bot in the same way as 'hello' command in botactivityHandler.js I am getting error message

Tags: javascript, node.js

Getting Error- SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
****const {
      TurnContext,
      MessageFactory,
    TeamsActivityHandler,
    CardFactory,
    ActionTypes
    } = require('botbuilder');
    class BotActivityHandler extends TeamsActivityHandler {
      constructor() {
        super();
```

/*  Teams bots are Microsoft Bot Framework bots.
If a bot receives a message activity, the turn handler sees that incoming activity
and sends it to the onMessage activity handler.
Learn more: https://aka.ms/teams-bot-basics.

```
        NOTE:   Ensure the bot endpoint that services incoming conversational bot queries is
                registered with Bot Framework.
                Learn more: https://aka.ms/teams-register-bot. 
    */
    // Registers an activity event handler for the message event, emitted for every incoming message activity.            
        
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            TurnContext.removeRecipientMention(context.activity);
            switch (context.activity.text.trim()) {
            case 'Hello':
                await this.mentionActivityAsync(context);
                break;
            case 'Bye':
                await this.mentionActivityAsync1(context);
                break;   
            default:
                // By default for unknown activity sent by user show
                // a card with the available actions.
                const value = { count: 0 };
                const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
                    'Lets talk...',
                    null,
                    [{
                        type: ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                        title: 'Say Hello',
                        value: value,
                        text: 'Hello'
                    }]);
                await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] });
                break;
            }
            await next();
        });
    }
```

/**
* Say hello and @ mention the current user.
*/

```
     async mentionActivityAsync(context) {
        const TextEncoder = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
        const mention = {
            mentioned: context.activity.from,
            text: `<at>${ new TextEncoder().encode(context.activity.from.name) }</at>`,
            type: 'mention'
        };
        const replyActivity = MessageFactory.text(`Hi ${ mention.text }`);
        replyActivity.entities = [mention];
        
        await context.sendActivity(replyActivity);
      }
    }
   async mentionActivityAsync1(context)  {
    const TextEncoder = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
    const mention = {
        mentioned: context.activity.from,
        text: `<at>${ new TextEncoder().encode(context.activity.from.name) }</at>`,
        type: 'mention'
    };
    const replyActivity = MessageFactory.text(`Bye ${ mention.text }`);
    replyActivity.entities = [mention];
    
    await context.sendActivity(replyActivity);
     }
      module.exports.BotActivityHandler = BotActivityHandler;****
```

Comment: If anyone has any inputs please let me know.